# Замыкание PHP возвращает объект

Tags: php, замыкания

Почему при использовании анонимной функции я не получаю true/false, как ожидаю, а вместо этого получаю объект класса Closure?

```
foreach ($objects as $object)
{
         $data[] = [
        'id' => $currBranch.$object->id,
        'text' => $object->name,
        'parent' => $model::$parent.$parent,
        'children' => function () use ($object, $with){  
                         if ($with){
                            return $object->$with() ? true : false; 
                          } else {
                            return false;                                 
                          }
                       },
        'currBranch' => $currBranch,
        'childBranch' => $object::$child,
        'childModel' => $object::$childModel,
       ];
}
```

Comment: Очевидно вы путаете замыкания и [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE). В PHP IIFE недоступны до 7-й версии.

Comment: я использую php 7.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044545/2118955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы не вызываете анонимную функцию, а только объявляете её.

```
$fn = function() {/**/};
```

Фактически это создание объекта класса [`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Если вы хотите вызвать анонимную функцию и получить её результат - то необходимо так и написать в коде.

```
$res = (function() {/**/})();
```

Либо через `call_user_func` либо

```
$fn = function() {/**/};
$res = $fn();
```

Либо ещё как, не уверен что вспомнил все возможности вызова функции.

---

Стоит отдельно подумать, зачем в вашем коде вообще анонимная функция.

```
'children' => ($with and $object->$with()),
```

На первый взгляд логика сохранена полностью.